# Can't run VS 2015 Community without /resetsettings; Getting CANTLOADLIBRARY on opening new projects, and crashing on new .cpp files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have Windows 10, fully updated.

I downloaded and installed Visual Studio Community 2015 last week for the first time, (previously programmed in Code:blocks, still installed) and selected custom install to allow for C++ and Python programming.

Installation ran smoothly, but VS always fails on launch.

On first launch ever, it said it was setting things up for first startup; asked me for sign-in which I did, at which point it briefly showed something about my profile before saying 'An error occurred while starting for the first time. Please restart Microsoft Visual Studio'. Imgur images of all dialog boxes [here](http://imgur.com/a/vFYyU), including parts of a processmonitor log I estimated to be around the general time of the error.

Closing and restarting several times didn't help.

Uninstalling and re-installing didn't help.

Rebooting didn't help.

And uninstalling, running Ccleaner's Cleaner and Registry Cleaner, rebooting computer and re-installing VS didn't help either.

Repairing the install from Programs also didn't help.

I managed to find the exact same error on Google Search for VS 2013 but the only solution was where one person got a completely new OS and re-installed VS on that.

I tried the other suggestions they had including running:

```
    devenv.exe /safemode
    devenv.exe /resetskippkgs
    devenv.exe /resetuserdata
    devenv.exe /installvstemplates
    devenv.exe /resetsettings
```

the first 3 took me to the same sign-in screen. Regardless of signing-in or not, or running VS from the Administrator Profile or not, these option always give the same failed on first startup error.

Installvstemplates gives an error saying the operation could not be completed, but /resetsettings finally got me into VS.

That's about all it does though, I can go to the home page and access options/menu buttons, but signing-in makes it crash and reload again (but it does sign me in and take me to the home screen)

Signed-in/not and Administrator or not, VS crashes on opening a new .cpp file.

When I click Start a New Project I get "Error loading type library/DLL.(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)). Closing VS and trying to open it normally from start menu still always throws the original error, despite working if I open it via /resetsettings.

I've also checked [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{73B7DC00-F498-4ABD-AB79-D07AFD52F395}\InProcServer32] in Regedit and found it is apparently correct.

I also used devenv /log to generate an [xml file](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8F7E7DEC1AA579E7!368&authkey=!AEmwAbp2sGVS53E&ithint=file%2cxml) of the process when I open it.

Just to mention I have .NET Framework 4.5-4.6 installed with VS as well.

Looking forward to any advice.

Answer (score 0):

So, for anyone else getting the same problem, I haven't gotten any other advice, since this post.

If you're still having probs @ this point the only real solution seems to be a clean install of your OS .

I can confirm it solved all my issues, with VS + some OS problems I wasn't aware of . I can only assume they might've been related, good luck.